# SMD diode identifying marking

Tags: diodes, identification

I need help to identify this diode, mark "AC C"

I attach photos of it I think there are SOD123.The caliper said 3,2x1,64

[image]

This is how they are in the PCB.

[image]

They are connected in this way.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Additional answer:

Possibly an Onsemi [NSI45020T1G](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nsi45020-d.pdf) or similar current regulator IC.
Three in parallel would be 60mA which is too much for a Tiny25 though.

[image]

---

Original answer:

It could be a [5V bidirectional transient suppressor](http://www.bencent.com.cn/index/xiazai/name/_Upfile_admin_pdf_5e4a3f56d1cef.pdf.html) if the package is much smaller than you imply.

[image]

Comment: Sorry something is wrong with te link.

Comment: @AdrianVeiga Works for me- downloads a pdf  directly.

Comment: I don't know what can happen, I have tried two computers and different browsers, maybe my internet provider.

Thank you very much with your help but it should not be that since before the led and positive there is + 10v

Comment: NSI45020T1G confirmed : https://assets.lcsc.com/images/lcsc/900x900/20230102_onsemi-NSI45020T1G_C129159_front.jpg